# Как сделать поиск в datagridview через textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

у меня есть поля в базе данных : фамилия, имя, Отчество, № договора, телефон, email и адрес.
на Windows Forms создал датагрид при  запуске  приложения осуществляется запрос, который показывает всю информацию о контрагенте, и мне нужно сделать поиск,
который  осуществляется через текстбокс в нем нужно как-то вместить 3 поля из базы данных,
т.е. проще говоря мне нужно чтобы пользователь введя ФИО нашел контрагента, но проблема в том что это 3 разных поля, не в одном поле прописано ФИО, а в разных, просто я привык искать в разных, вот и не знаю как можно сделать, попробовал по разному но не получилось(
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать?

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox3.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код своей попытки решения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте говорящие имена всем своим переменным, в том числе и контролам. Вот что такое `textBox3`? О чём говорит это имя?

Так как этот текстбокс предназначен для поиска, назовём его `SearchTextBox`. И так далее.

---

Навскидку код может выглядеть так. Текст, введённый в поле поиска расщепляем по пробелу, получаем несколько значений. По ним и ищем.

Я использовал `row.Cells["FirstName"]`, `row.Cells["LastName"]` - явное указание колонок с именем и фамилией, но можно и циклом пробегаться по колонкам.

```
private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.ClearSelection();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTextBox.Text))
        return;

    var values = searchTextBox.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            var row = dataGridView.Rows[i];

            if (row.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString().Contains(value) ||
                row.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString().Contains(value))
            {
                row.Selected = true;                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Я не знаю, какой именно поиск вам нужен - точное совпадение всех полей в одной строке или частичное совпадение в разных строках.

Возможно, больше подойдут следующие условия:

```
if (row.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString().Contains(value))
{
    row.Cells["FirstName"].Selected = true;
}

if (row.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString().Contains(value))
{
    row.Cells["LastName"].Selected = true;
}
```

Тут выделяется не строка целиком, а отдельные ячейки.

---

Или такой вариант:

```
if (values.Length != 2)
    return;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    var row = dataGridView.Rows[i];

    if (row.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString().Contains(values[0]) &&
        row.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString().Contains(values[1]))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

---

Совет: используйте датагрид с двойной буферизацией. Это намного ускоряет его отрисовку.

```
class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered { get => true; }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!